# Create object in MapBasic and taking information from table to fill objects features

Tags: mapbasic

I'm currently using MapBasic 16 version. What I'm trying to do is define a function that can create a point that can be activated with a button. When the process of placing a point is complete, I want it to automatically retrieve information within the polygon where the point is placed (such as city, district name) and input additional information to write to a new table.

I need to retrieve coordinates to use the function that can create a point, and I'm using the following commands for this:

```
x = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_X) 
y = CommandInfo(CMD_INFO_Y)
o = CreatePoint(x,y)
insert into point(obj) values (o)
```

However, when no object is selected, the CommandInfo function returns table and row values instead of x and y coordinates. How can I retrieve the information from the selected object without having to select it first?